# Visual Studio 2008 Find in Files not working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, findinfiles

I am having a really bizarre problem. Find in Files feature in VS2008 always finds zero matches when looking in the Entire Solution and gives the error 'No files were found to look in' when looking in Current Project. Looking in Current Document works just fine.

I've tried the ctrl+scroll lock thing with no success. Also, my folders aren't mark as system folders as some people suggested.

Any help on this is appreciated, a life without find in files is a life of deceit and dismay... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your find dialog, expand the **Find Options** section.

Make sure that the **Look at there file types:** is either blank, or `*.*`

Comment: yeah that was the problem... i've realized that a moment ago... thanks!

Comment: @Pedro - If only I could count the number of times I've done this...and it's **still** not the first thing I check :(

Answer (score 4):

Yeah pain in the neck, use this AWSOME free tool instead:

Agent Ransack

http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/Page.aspx?page=download

Comment: Once installed, open it. Select the folder to search, check the "contains text" checkbox and start search.

Comment: This not only shows you the line of text you are searching will show each file the text is found in. each line of code for each file and their line number. I had too many issues with search in vs, when it does work, it is touchy and not accurate at times. Since I installed Agent Ransack i haven't looked back. lightweight too.

Comment: really good program indeed, just done some testing, it's really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Aww I've found it. The problem was that there was a filter that said only .asmx files should be looked into.... No idea how did this happen, though...